# How to retry in Cassandra if Read timeout occurs

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I was getting `ReadTimeoutException` quite frequently in my production Cassandra Cluster (10 nodes). So, to reproduce this issue in my local dev environment (Cassandra Cluster of four nodes), I ran my code and then stopped two CassandraDaemon. I got following exception

> Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replica available for query at consistency ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException.copy(UnavailableException.java:79)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:269)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$MultiPage.prepareNextRow(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:285)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$MultiPage.isExhausted(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:245)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$1.hasNext(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:126)
>       at com.cleartrail.keyspacedatamigrator.migrator.Migrator.migrateTimeline(Migrator.java:376)
>       at com.cleartrail.keyspacedatamigrator.migrator.Migrator.migrateData(Migrator.java:267)
>       at TestMigration.main(TestMigration.java:9)
>   Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replica available for query at consistency ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException.copy(UnavailableException.java:79)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:94)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$MultiPage$1.onSet(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:352)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:183)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2300(RequestHandler.java:45)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:748)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:587)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:991)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:913)
>       at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324)
>       at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:254)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:242)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:847)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replica available for query at consistency ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:48)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:37)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:213)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:204)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:89)
>       ... 13 more

My Cassandra connection code looks like this

```
SocketOptions so = new SocketOptions();
so.setReadTimeoutMillis(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
so.setConnectTimeoutMillis(sockettimeoutinmillis);

Builder builder = new Cluster.Builder().
                addContactPoints(connectionpoints).withPort(port);

builder.withPoolingOptions(new PoolingOptions().setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, new PoolingOptions().getMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL)));

cluster = builder
               .withRetryPolicy(DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
               .withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(10000L))
               .build();

session=cluster.connect();
```

I have provided retry policy while connecting to Cassandra, then why am I getting such exception?
I haven't written any specific code to handle the `ReadTimeoutException` and retry. Is any specific code or handling required?

Answer (score 2):

If you want custom logic for handling Read/Write Timeout and UnavailableExceptions you can implement your own custom [`RetryPolicy`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/RetryPolicy.html).

You can override the `onReadTimeout` method to behave exactly as you desire.

The exception you provided however is an `UnavailableException` which is a cassandra coordinator telling you that no replicas are available to complete your query (meaning in this case that all replicas owning the data you are trying to read are marked DOWN in C*), therefore it did not even try and failed fast.   In this case, retrying is probably not going to provide much value since you are likely to experience the same result.   Based on the `RetryPolicy` you specified (`DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy`) what likely happened is that either a ReadTimeout or UnavailableException was encountered, and the RetryPolicy tried again at a lower ConsistencyLevel (ONE) and still failed because another UnavailableException is encountered.

A few questions for you which may help gain clarity:

1. What replication factor are you using for the Keyspace you are working with?  You mention 4 nodes in your dev environment.  If 1 node goes down and you have an RF of 1, then it's likely that 25% of your queries will hit an UnavailableException.
2. What consistency level are you querying with?  If you aren't providing one, you are always using 'ONE' anyways, so DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy probably isn't benefitting you.

Comment: I am aware about the custom implementation of `Retry Policy`. But I was hoping to use existing implementation as in above code. Also

Comment: Depending on your Replication factor and Consistency Level a particular RetryPolicy available in the driver may help you.  Can you share those details?

Comment: 1. I am using `Replication Factor 2` in my local as well as production keyspace. But in production, all the ten nodes are up and I still get this exception. I guess there is a lot of data in keyspace which is creating the problem because query like "Select * FROM keyspace.table" will scan the whole table.

2. Yes, I haven't specified any Consistency Level while querying the data and maybe that's the reason retry policy is not working.

Comment: My whole use case is, to load data faster into Cassandra, I use SSTableLoader and uploaded very huge no. of SSTables into my keyspace and now these SSTables are not getting compacted and querying on any table from that keyspace gives above exception.